# Previous and next image link in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help for the slider on **TweenMax.js**

**The problem:**

This example has 4 images, on click each images will open in a fullscreen.
But i am not getting the previous screen link and next screen link in fullscreen.

**Expected Result:** once image is clicked, it should get previous image hyperlink and next hyperlink in all the sliders

**Please Note :** Now it is working for last image and first image.
even though i click any image

Please accept my apologies, CODE is very big !

**JSFIDDLE :**

[**http://jsfiddle.net/goo08gg5/11/**](http://jsfiddle.net/goo08gg5/11/)

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I feel this place in JS, we need to make the changes, but i might be wrong

```
//next image link
TweenLite.set($expander_nav.last(), {
    x : 160,
    right : 4,
    left : 'auto',
    delay : delay
});
//first image link
TweenLite.set($expander_nav.first(), {
    x : -160,
    left : 4,
    right : 'auto',
    delay : delay,
    onComplete : function () {
        // add content to title overlay after delay
        $title.html(self.$cur_circle.siblings('.tagline').html());
    }
});
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var HeroCircles = function(el) {
    this.$el = $(el);
    this.$circles = this.$el.find('.circle');
    this.$expander = this.$el.find('.circle-expander');
    this.$cur_circle = null;
  };

  HeroCircles.prototype._placeBG = function() {

    // get parent position and dimensions
    var self = this,
        parent_pos = this.$el.offset(),
        parent_width = this.$el.width(),
        parent_height = this.$el.height();

    this.$circles.each(function() {
      var $circle = $(this),
          offset = $circle.offset(),
          $bg = $circle.children('.bg');

      // set position
      $bg.css({
        'top': parent_pos.top - offset.top + 'px',
        'left': parent_pos.left - offset.left + 'px',
        'width': parent_width + 'px',
        'height': parent_height + 'px'
      });
    });

  };

  HeroCircles.prototype._animateInTitle = function(delay) {
    var self = this,
        $title = this.$expander.children('.title-overlay'),
        cur_class = this.$cur_circle.data('name'),
        $expander_nav = this.$expander.children('.expander-nav').children('a').not('.' + cur_class);

    TweenLite.set($expander_nav.last(), { x: 160, right: 4,  left: 'auto', delay: delay });
//Last image
    TweenLite.set($expander_nav.first(), {
      x: -160,
      left: 4,
      right: 'auto',
      delay: delay,
      onComplete: function() {
        // add content to title overlay after delay
        $title.html(self.$cur_circle.siblings('.tagline').html());
      }
    });
//Firstimage
    // animate in title overlay
    TweenLite.to($title, 0.5, {
      y: 40,
      delay: delay,
      ease: Back.easeOut
    });

    TweenLite.to($expander_nav, 0.15, {
      x: 0,
      delay: delay + 0.5
    });
  };

  HeroCircles.prototype._animateOutTitle = function() {
    var $title = this.$expander.children('.title-overlay'),
        cur_class = this.$cur_circle.data('name'),
        $expander_nav = this.$expander.children('.expander-nav').children('a').not('.' + cur_class);

    // animate out title overlay
    TweenLite.to($title, 0.5, {
      y: $title.outerHeight()
    });

    // animate out circles
    TweenLite.to($expander_nav.first(), 0.15, {
      x: -160
    });
    TweenLite.to($expander_nav.last(), 0.15, {
      x: 160
    });
  };

  HeroCircles.prototype._animateIn = function(circle) {
    var $circle = $(circle),
        $border = $circle.siblings('.border'),
        img = $circle.children('.bg').data('bg');

    // set current circle
    this.$cur_circle = $circle;

    // set bg image for expander div
    this.$expander.css('z-index', 4);
    this.$expander.children('.bg').css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')');

    // add active class to li
    $circle.parent('li').addClass('active');

    // expand circle
    TweenLite.to($border, 0.3, {
      scale: 7
    });

    // fade in expander
    TweenLite.to(this.$expander, 0.5, {
      opacity: 1,
      delay: 0.5,
      onComplete: function() {
        TweenLite.set($border, { scale: 1 });
      }
    });

    // animate in title overlay
    this._animateInTitle(1);
  };

  HeroCircles.prototype._animateOut = function() {
    var self = this;

    // remove active class and scale down border
    this.$el.find('li').removeClass('active');

    // animate out title
    this._animateOutTitle();

    // fade out expander
    TweenLite.to(this.$expander, 0.5, {
      opacity: 0,
      delay: 0.5,
      onComplete: function() {
        self.$expander.css({
          'z-index': -1
        });
      }
    });

  };

  HeroCircles.prototype._animateSwitch = function(circle) {
    this._animateOutTitle();

    this.$cur_circle = $(circle);

    var img = this.$cur_circle.children('.bg').data('bg'),
        $bg = this.$expander.children('.bg');

    // switch active class
    this.$el.find('li').removeClass('active');
    this.$cur_circle.parent('li').addClass('active');

    TweenLite.to($bg, 0.3, {
      opacity: 0,
      delay: 0.5,
      onComplete: function() {
        $bg.css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')');
        TweenLite.to($bg, 0.3, { opacity: 1 });
      }
    });

    this._animateInTitle(1);
  };

  HeroCircles.prototype.init = function() {
    var self = this;

    this._placeBG();

    // add click events
    this.$el.on('click', '.circle', function() {
      self._animateIn(this);
    });
    this.$el.find('.close-btn').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      self._animateOut();
    });
    this.$expander.children('.expander-nav').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var new_class = $(this).attr('class'),
          $circle = self.$el.find('ul .' + new_class);

      console.log("new class is", new_class, "new circle is", $circle[0]);
      self._animateSwitch($circle);
    });
  };

  HeroCircles.prototype.initMobile = function() {
    var self = this,
        $mobile_slider = this.$el.find('.mobile-slider');

    this.$el.on('click', '.circle', function() {
      var $this = $(this),
          bg = $this.children('.bg').data('bg');

      self.$circles.removeClass('active');
      $this.addClass('active');

      $mobile_slider.html('<div>' + $this.siblings('.tagline').html() + '</div>');
      $mobile_slider.css('background-image', 'url(' + bg + ')');
    });

    this.$circles.first().trigger('click');
  };

  var hero_circles = new HeroCircles('.hero-circles');
  if ( window.innerWidth > 580 ) {
    hero_circles.init();
  } else {
    hero_circles.initMobile();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have make

> **Expected Result:** once image is clicked, it should get previous image
>   hyperlink and next hyperlink in all the sliders

But i dont know how work this `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` circle.

This script work fine for next and prev slide, but the animation slide is no good. but it's work !

I have add a index of clicked circle for next and prev slide.

please see: http://jsfiddle.net/gw4eqg92/